# How to access the different array fields in this link?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Recently, I am having problem while displaying the changing data from my dummy website. it shows array of integers and but I don't know how to access the different array. the link is: [click here](http://www.vitacademicsrel.appspot.com/marks/13bit0084/28091995)

But to show content of above link you'll have to visit [this link](http://www.vitacademicsrel.appspot.com/captchaless/13bit0084/28091995) first.

I want take the data from there and show it in another web page using PHP, CURL or HTML if possible.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and explain what you're trying to do better? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please add code to this question directly as posting links in questions is not good stack overflow etiquette. This site is designed to be useful for not just you but all who look at your question after. If your link dies then this question is not worth anything to the coding community.

Comment: As per Glenn's advice, I am voting to close this - external links will not always demonstrate the problem as the question gets older. I generally recommend avoiding external links entirely, to encourage you to present a replicable code example in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have arrays of arrays. This response is rather messy, it might be worth refactoring if you don't need it to be this way.

To get the elements in the array you are going to need to use multidimensional array accessors

```
$value1 = $array[0][0][0] // $value1 = "1"
$value2 = $array[0][0][1] // $value2 = "1702"
$value3 = $array[0][1][2] // $value3 = "ITE205"
```

etc.